# Grid export table data is not working in IE 10 and mozilla

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working with kendo ui controls,when  export the table data 
from grid is working fine in chrome but it's not working in IE 10  and mozilla firefox.
Here is my code with fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/SZBrt/41/`enter code here`

```
   var data = filteredDataSource.view();

    var result = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel,";

 result += "<table><tr><th>OrderID</th><th>Freight</th><th>Order Date</th><th>Ship Name</th><th>Ship City</th></tr>";

 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     result += "<tr>";

     result += "<td>";
     result += data[i].OrderID;
     result += "</td>";

     result += "<td>";
     result += data[i].Freight;
     result += "</td>";

     result += "<td>";
     result += kendo.format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", data[i].OrderDate);
     result += "</td>";

     result += "<td>";
     result += data[i].ShipName;
     result += "</td>";
     result += "<td>";
     result += data[i].ShipCity;
     result += "</td>";
     result += "</tr>";
 }
  result += "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed your approach is currently supported only in Chrome. For Firefox you would need window.open and for IE 10 - [window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh779016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([result]), 'export.csv');
 } else {
   window.open(result);
 }
```

Here is the updated fiddle which works in Firefox and IE 10: http://jsfiddle.net/SZBrt/92/

A lot of info is available in this blog post: http://hackworthy.blogspot.com/2012/05/savedownload-data-generated-in.html

Comment: hi atans it's working fine but while i am checking in chrome with same code downloded 2  files (1)download.xls,2)exportdeata).so can we have any option to enable that code in  IE and Mozilla?

Comment: Yes,I have deleted the older code but the exact problem is when I removed that the export file name is getting as download instead of my own file name and one more problem is the exported data is not getting in IE as excel data